# ComboBox ItemList SelectedValue

Tags: vb.net, combobox, datasource, list.selectedvalue

VB.NET (2010)

I'm trying to create a ComboBox with a Value and Display items. Here are the relevant bits of code. I originally tried to use a datatable with exactly the same result:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        cmbFromGroup.Items.Clear()
        ItemList.Clear()
        Item = New SelectionItem(KeyValue, DisplayValue)
        'Link combobox and Item
        ItemList.Add(Item)
        cmbFromGroup.DataSource = ItemList
        cmbFromGroup.DisplayMember = "Display"
        cmbFromGroup.ValueMember = "Key"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Stop
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub cmbFromGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbFromGroup.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        cmbFromMP3.Items.Clear()
        Dim x As String = cmbFromGroup.SelectedValue
        ' <snip>
        cmbFromMP3.SelectedIndex = 0
    Catch ex As Exception
        Stop
    End Try
End Sub

Public Interface ISelectionItem
    Property Key As String
    Property Display As String
End Interface

Public Class SelectionItem
    Implements ISelectionItem

    Public Sub New(ByVal vKey As String, ByVal vDisplay As String)
        _Key = vKey
        _Display = vDisplay
    End Sub

    Public Property Key As String Implements ISelectionItem.Key
    Public Property Display As String Implements ISelectionItem.Display

End Class
```

The problem I'm having is that cmbFromGroup.SelectedValue doesn't contain the value of the selected item.

What I'm getting is (from Watch)
cmbFromGroup.SelectedValue  {Player.SelectionItem}  Object

The only options I get from cmbFromGroup.SelectedValue are Equals,GetHashCode, GetType, ReferenceEquals and ToString, none of which give me the ValueMember as I'm expecting.

How do I get the ValueMember from the selected item?

Answer (score 3):

Use `.text` on the Combo:

```
Dim x As String = cmbFromGroup.text
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I eventually came up with is

```
cmbFromGroup.SelectedIndex = -1
```

Then trap for that in the cmbFromGroup_SelectedIndexChanged sub.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and managed to use a Database (Using a Stored Procedure).
Here are the relevant bits of Code

```
'On Form load or Button Click (Depending on your application)
conString.Open() 'change conString to your connection string name
'Set Command for the stored procedure
Dim sqlComGetDirectorates As New SqlCommand
With sqlComGetDirectorates
     .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
     .Connection = conString
     .CommandText = "ProcGetDirectorates" 'your stored procedure name
     'if your stored procedure has parameters
     '.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficerIdentity", txtPNum.Text) 
End With

'Create Data Adapter (Using the stored procedure Command created earlier)
' Create a data table and Fill the Data adapter 
Dim DatadptDirectorates As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlComGetDirectorates)
Dim dattabDirectorates As New DataTable
DatadptDirectorates.Fill(dattabDirectorates)
'Your Combobox 
ComboDirectorate.DataSource = dattabDirectorates
ComboDirectorate.DisplayMember = "DirectorateName"
ComboDirectorate.ValueMember = "DirectorateCode"
'User will see DisplayMember in the Combobox
```

'on SelectedIndexChanged of the Combobox

txtDirectorate.Text = ComboDirectorate.SelectedItem(1)

''NOTE: Combobox.SelectedItem will internally Get a ROW from the result of the ''Stored Procedure
''You need to obtain the value you need by specifying the combobox.selecteditem(??)
''In your result (from stored procedure) you have columns 0 - xx, chose the appropriate number for (??)

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to tie a value to a *ComboBox* item, What i ended up doing was something like:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim ValuesList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i = 1 To 10
            ComboBox1.Items.Add("Item" & i)
            ValuesList.Add("Value" & i)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
        Dim selectedItem = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
        Dim selectedItemValue As String = ValuesList.Item(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
        MsgBox(selectedItem & " " & selectedItemValue)
    End Sub
End Class
```